# $\pi_n(X^n)$ free Abelian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I have encountered a problem which states that denote $X$ as an Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,1)$ and is a CW complex, show that $\pi_n(X^n)$ is free Abelian for $n \geqslant 2$.

However, I think I have a conceptual misunderstanding in this problem. According to cellular approximation, the map

\begin{equation}
f:  (S^n, s_0) \rightarrow (X,x_0)
\end{equation}

can be homotoped to a cellular map so that it maps $(S^n,s_0)$ into $X^n$. In this sense the $\pi_n(X^n)$ should be equal to $\pi_n(X)$, which is actually zero.

I would appreciate for clarification in this case. Moreover, how do we show that the homotopy group is free Abelian?

Comment: It is true that the map can be homotoped into $X^n$.  But, it becomes trivial due to the $X^{n+1}$ and $X^{n+2}$ skeletons, which $X^n$ lacks.

Comment: For the reason mentioned above, it's a standard result that the inclusion $X^n \to X$ induces an isomorphism on homotopy groups below dimension $n$ and a surjection in dimension $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joe Johnson 126's answer is incorrect; see [Is it true that $\pi_n(X^{n-1})=0$ for $n>1$ if $X$ is $K(G,1)$ space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690795/is-it-true-that-pi-nxn-1-0-for-n1-if-x-is-kg-1-space).  Indeed, the claimed statement is very much *not* true for all CW-complexes.  For instance, if $X=S^3$, then $\pi_4(X^4)=\pi_4(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Here is a correct answer.  First of all, to address the first question, all your argument shows is that the map $\pi_n(X^n)\to\pi_n(X)$ is *surjective*.  You know that every map $S^n\to X$ can be homotoped to a map $S^n\to X^n$, but it might be that two such maps are homotopic in $X$ but not in $X^n$.  A homotopy of such maps is a map $S^n\times I\to X$, which by cellular approximation can only be homotoped to $X^{n+1}$, since $S^n\times I$ is $(n+1)$-dimensional.  So you do have an isomorphism $\pi_n(X^{n+1})\to \pi_n(X)$.

Let's now solve the original problem.  Note that by the argument above, $\pi_k(X^n)\cong \pi_k(X)$ for all $k<n$, so since $X$ is a $K(G,1)$, $\pi_k(X^n)$ is trivial for $k<n$ except for $k=1$.  Let $Y$ be the universal cover of $X^n$; then $Y$ is also an $n$-dimensional CW-complex, and now $\pi_k(Y)=0$ for all $k<n$.  By Hurewicz, we have $\pi_n(Y)\cong H_n(Y)$.  But $H_n$ of any $n$-dimensional CW-complex is free abelian (because computing cellular homology, there are no nontrivial $(n+1)$-chains and hence no nontrivial $n$-boundaries, so $H_n$ is just the group of $n$-cycles, which is a subgroup of the free abelian group of $n$-chains).  Thus $\pi_n(Y)$ is free abelian, and hence so is $\pi_n(X^n)\cong \pi_n(Y)$.